# Combine Google map's searchbox api and geocoder api together in one input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I want to use one input to search:

1. search keywords

ex: 'taiwan'

2. search latitude and longitude

ex: '22, 23'

searchBox is used as following:

```
// listen the searchBox input event 'places_changed'
const pacInput = document.getElementById('pac-input')
const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(pacInput)
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
   ...
})
```

geocoder is used as following:

```
// by click or any event you want to trigger
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
geocoder.geocode({
    location: latLng
  }, (results, status) => {
     ...
})
```

Google map can do this two feature in one input, is it possible to combine them together?

(I have listened to the place of change. If there is no place then search the latitude and longitude. But I found out that once the place change triggers, it will always have a place in the result, so it won't search latitude and longitude.)

Comment: Post complete code if you want people to understand what you are trying to do. Regarding the issue, one question: why do you need the geocoder? You can search for coordinates using the searchBox.

Comment: Can searchBox search latitude and longitude? Is there any sample by javascript? By the way, now I check the input format (split ',' and only number) to determine which function to continue in place change manually.

Comment: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2NhsE/) for a standard implementation of the SearchBox. I seem to be able to search for coordinates. What might happen though is that it "understands" some coordinates and treats others as an address or whatever so you may get unexpected and inconsistent results. So in the end, checking for the value of the field and using the geocoder might be a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a workaround using javascript. Please use **[this](https://jsbin.com/nekugux/edit?html,output)** as a reference. I modified your code. You need to add a condition that checks if it is an address or coordinates.

```
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        var addressSplit = address.split(',');
        var geo;
        var addressObj;

        if ( addressSplit.length !== 2 ) {
          addressObj = { 'address' : address };
        } else {
          var lat = addressSplit[0].replace(/\s/g, '');
          var lng = addressSplit[1].replace(/\s/g, '');
          if ( !isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng) ) {
            addressObj =  { 'location' : { 'lat' : parseFloat( lat ), 'lng' : parseFloat( lng ) } };
          } else {
            addressObj = { 'address' : address };
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I do now. :D

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer. :)